# How to achieve Pivot property (or output) using mysql based on information of another table that can be updated dynamically

Tags: mysql

I want to represent a column data as row in table...

I have 3 Input tables..

```
             Person

  Id   |   Name |  age   | Country
 ----- | :----: | :----: | :-----:
   1   |  anil  |   20   |  India
   2   |  Raggu |   21   |  India
   3   |  IRSHAD|   22   |  India
   4   |  Sravas|   20   |  India
   5   |    .   |   .    |   .
   6   |    .   |   .    |   .
   7   |    .   |   .    |   .
```

---

```
             Test

  Id   |   Name   |   description   
 ----- | :----:   | :-------------: 
   1   |  Height  |   Height of a person in feets   
   2   |  Weight  |   Weight of a person in kgs 
   3   |  Fat     |   Fat of a person in calories  
   4   |    .     |        .
   5   |    .     |        .
   6   |    .     |        .
   7   |    .     |        .
```

---

```
             Gim

 Person_Id   | Test_Id |  value   
 ---------   | :----:  | :----: 
   1         |     1   |   6 
   2         |     3   |   120  
   1         |     2   |   60   
   4         |     1   |   5.8    
   6         |     .   |   .    
   7         |     .   |   .
```

---

I need Out Table as

```
             Gim_Result

   Name |  Height| Weight |  Fat   |....
 :----: | :----: | :-----:|:-----: |
  anil  |   6    |   60   | null   | .....
  Raggu |   null |   null | 120    | .....
  IRSHAD|   null |  null  | null   | ....
  Sravas|   5.8  |  null  | null   | ....
   .    |    .   |   .    |   .    | .....
   .    |    .   |   .    |   .    | .....
   .    |    .   |   .    |   .    | .....
```

I need a query such that it will produce result as i shown above table
It dynamically generate new column in Result Table for each different Test in Test Table

What i think we can generate this type of result using pivot in sql server

but i need to generate this result using mysql...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Comment: in my case i don't know what fields exits in Test table and when new test added in test table my static query automatically generate output table with new test as column also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic principle looks like this:

```
SELECT
    EntityID
  , SUM(CASE WHEN PivotColumn = 'PivotColumnValue1' THEN PivotValue ELSE NULL END)
  , SUM(CASE WHEN PivotColumn = 'PivotColumnValue2' THEN PivotValue ELSE NULL END)
  /* ... */
  , SUM(CASE WHEN PivotColumn = 'PivotColumnValueN' THEN PivotValue ELSE NULL END)
FROM
  MyTable
GROUP BY
  EntityID
;
```

You can of course use any aggregation function of your choice.

Comment: in my case i don't know what field exits in Test table and when new test added in test table my query automatically generate output table with new test column

Comment: There is no dynamic pivot solution in sql servers. If you want to implement it, you'll have to use dynamic sql.